# How to merge multiple sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `Users`. I am trying out to grab some data from it with the following query:

```
select name, lastname, gender, status, count(status = 'Trvl') as TrvlCount,
       count(status != 'Trvl') as NotTrvlCount, count(id) as TotalCount
from Users
group by name, lastname, gender, dob;
```

The expected result would be 7 columns with unique name, lastname,gender, dob (to avoid duplicates) and sum of different statuses. But I cant rectify why all 3 count columns are showing the same value or same sum value?

Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." I.e. I'd try `group by name, lastname, gender, status`.

Comment: but still i get the same result jarlh

Comment: COUNT will just count rows, try SUM instead if you're trying to count how many rows match those conditions (it works just because TRUE equals 1 and FALSE equals 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **sum if** construction:

```
select name, lastname, gender, status, 
       sum(if(status = 'Trvl',  1, 0)) as TrvlCount,
       sum(if(status != 'Trvl',  1, 0)) as NotTrvlCount,
       count(id) as TotalCount
from Users
group by name, lastname, gender, dob;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, lastname, gender, status, 
       (SELECT COUNT() FROM Users WHERE status = 'Trvl') as TrvlCount,
       (SELECT COUNT() FROM Users WHERE status <> 'Trvl') as NotTrvlCount,
       count(id) as TotalCount
from Users
group by name, lastname, gender, dob;
```

Also you can do it with subqueries.